# Prevent hotlinking/access to mp4 files

Tags: php, mysql, mp4, uniq

I have a website created with PHP where I play mp4 files through a flash player or html5 player. Recently I see that my files are on other websites too and it cost me bandwidth.

I use httpd/apache on the remote host, where the mp4 files are stored.
On the website, I use nginx.

I have some knowledge in PHP and MySQL but I don't know how to do this. How can I make them accessible only through my website?

Answer (score 2):

Example 1, block all hotlinking (when detectable)

```
location ~* (\.png)$ {
   valid_referers blocked mysite.com www.mysite.com;
   if ($invalid_referer) {
       return 405;
   }     
}
```

Example 2, redirect hotlinked files only for some sites

```
location ~* (\.mp4)$ {
   if ($http_referer ~ ^(http://www.bad.com|http://stupid.com) ) {
       # Redirect to a specific file
       #rewrite  ^/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/dont-hotlink.html last; 

       # Redirect to a dynamic url where /hotlinked/ is some script that
       # displays some info about the hotlinked file.
       rewrite  ^/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/hotlinked/$1/ last; 
   }   
}
```

Source : 
[Redirect or block hotlinked files with nginx](http://kuttler.eu/code/redirect-hotlinked-files-nginx/)

Comment: Just remember that http referers are TRIVIAL to forge, and not all browsers send them anyways. This will help, but it's not a magic bullet. On the other hand, this is an nginx solution, and OP said he's running Apache...

Comment: hello,
thank you for answering.


i use httpd on host where mp4 files are stored.
also, if i block hotlinking, will that not block from website? website and mp4 files are not on same webhost.